# Prove the inequality about $Re(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Consider three different vectors $x$,$y$ and $z$ in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. So $x = (x_{1} \dots x_{n})$ and this is the same for $y$ and $z$.
Now we have $\langle x,y\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_{i}\bar{y_{i}}}$ and we have $\langle x,x\rangle = \langle y,y\rangle = \langle z,z\rangle = 1$

Now the question is : prove
$$\Re{(1-\langle x,y\rangle)(1-\langle y,z\rangle)(1-\langle z,x\rangle)} > 0$$

My attempt : I tried to rewrite it in another case , using fact that our dot product is $1$ and tried to get some relation about $x,y $ and $z$. But that doesn't give me anything. 
Any ideas?

Actually I tried to represent it in any possible forms and get the sum. Next tried using $\Re({\sum{z}}) = \sum{\Re({z})}$

Comment: @AD. actually any x , y and z

Comment: @AD. I understand, okay three different vectors